# Using values within different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, stripe-payments

I have 2 arrays retrieved from a db and stripe respectively. Both data were mapped using a common field. In attempting to process charges, I get this error `StripeInvalidRequestError ---- There is currently another in-progress request using this Stripe token`. Meaning the loop definitely runs twice. So my question is how do I efficiently achieve using data from both arrays without looping twice?

Any thoughts, please?

```
array1 = [ 
  { totalCharge:  10000 },
  { totalCharge:  30000 },
]

 array2 = [
   { customer: 63667363,
     source:  "kssgjag_98899"
   },
   { customer: 767897889
     source:  "hkhdgd_93762"
   },
 ]

 for (let x of array1){
    for (let y of array2){
       stripe.charges.create({
           amount: x.totalCharge,
           currency: "usd",
           customer: y.id,
           source: y.source
       }, function(err, charge) {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're only visiting each combination of x and y once. From the error and the code, I'd say the problem is you're not allowed to have more than one outstanding action with Stripe (whereas with the above, you're starting four actions nearly simultaneously, without waiting for the previous ones to finish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only visiting each combination of x and y once (total of four combinations), but from subsequent comments it appears that you don't want to do that, you want to make *two* charges: 10000 for kssgjag_98899 and 30000 for hkhdgd_93762.

The simplest thing to do is probably build yourself a single array of charges to make, then process it one charge at a time.

Building the array:

```
if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    throw new Error("Arrays should be of the same length");
}
const charges = array1.map(({totalCharge}, index) {
    const {id, source} = array2[index];
    return {
        amount: totalCharge,
        currency: "usd",
        customer: id,
        source
    };
});
```

Processing them one at a time: [Nicolas Takashi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401684/nicolas-takashi) told me in a comment on a now-deleted answer that in addition to having a callback, `stripe.charges.create` *also* returns a promise. If so, you can use the classic promise `reduce` trick:

```
const promiseForResult = charges.reduce(
    (p, charge) => p.then(() => stripe.charges.create(charge)),
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

That will ensure that you only have one call to `stripe.charges.create` happening at any given time.

If it's okay for the calls to overlap (but from your error it sounds like it isn't), you'd use `Promise.all` instead:

```
const promiseForResult = Promise.all(
    charges.map(charge => stripe.charges.create(charge))
);
```

If it's *not* true that `stripe.charges.create` returns a promise, you can easily give yourself a wrapper that does:

```
const createCharge = charge => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    strip.charges.create(charge, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and then either one-at-a-time:

```
const promiseForResult = charges.reduce(
    (p, charge) => p.then(() => createCharge(charge)),
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

or all at once:

```
const promiseForResult = Promise.all(charges.map(createCharge));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that results in a new array `array3` that has the zipped up result.

```
const array1 = [ 
  { totalCharge:  10000 },
  { totalCharge:  30000 },
]

 const array2 = [
   { customer: 63667363,
     source:  "kssgjag_98899"
   },
   { customer: 767897889,
     source:  "hkhdgd_93762"
   },
 ]

const array3 = [];
for (let x of array1) {
  for (let y of array2) {
    array3.push({
      amount: x.totalCharge,
      currency: "usd",
      customer: y.customer,
      source: y.source
    });
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

Output:

```
[
    {"amount":10000,"currency":"usd","customer":63667363,"source":"kssgjag_98899"},
    {"amount":10000,"currency":"usd","customer":767897889,"source":"hkhdgd_93762"},
    {"amount":30000,"currency":"usd","customer":63667363,"source":"kssgjag_98899"},
    {"amount":30000,"currency":"usd","customer":767897889,"source":"hkhdgd_93762"}
]
```

You will need to make a charge request from your server for each of these, waiting for the previous request to complete before starting the next:

```
function processCharges(charges: any[], index = 0) {
  stripe.charges.create(charges[index], (err, charge) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    }

    index++;
    if (index < charges.length) {
      processCharges(charges, index);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The edit's way of handling the charges is a nice pattern. I've seen it, and used it, and yet didn't use it in my answer for some reason...

Comment: @Fenton Array3 still returns a duplicate therefore still giving the same error

Comment: @Hopez - There are no duplicates in `array3` above (or `charges` in my answers, which I build the same way). Each combination of `x` and `y` is unique.

Comment: I meant your output array. It returns 4 objects too therefore still having same error @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Hopez: You have **two charges**. You have **two clients**. Your code is producing a cartesian product of those; 2 x 2 = 4. Is it that you just want the first charge for the first client, and the second charge for the second client (total of two charges made, 10000 for kssgjag_98899 and 30000 for hkhdgd_93762)? If so, your question doesn't remotely make that clear.

Comment: Yeah. That was what I wanted. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Hopez - I've added to the end of my answer.